# What the heck is going on with my cron scheduler? (rsnapshot)

Tags: cron, scheduling, rsnapshot

## CRONTABS

I'm using rsnapshot with cron. Here's what `sudo crontab -l` shows me.

```
0 */4           * * *   /usr/bin/rsnapshot hourly
30 3    * * *           /usr/bin/rsnapshot daily
0  3    * * 1           /usr/bin/rsnapshot weekly
```

## OUTPUT

I went to check on the backup folder to see if everything is working correctly, but here is the time sorted output:

```
elijah@degas:~$ ls -lt /media/backup/
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 May 30 04:00 hourly.1
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 May 23 04:00 hourly.2
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 May 17 04:00 hourly.3
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 May 14 04:00 hourly.4
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 May 13 04:00 hourly.5
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 May 12 04:00 daily.0
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 May 10 04:00 daily.1
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 May  7 04:00 daily.2
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 May  4 04:00 daily.3
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Apr 29 16:00 daily.4
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Apr 28 20:00 daily.5
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Apr 28 16:04 hourly.0
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Apr 28 12:21 daily.6
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Apr 27 10:09 weekly.1
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Apr 25 07:23 weekly.3
```

The output seems almost random! Why could this be happening? I have what I thought was an identical configuration on a different machine, and it seems to be working fine.

## SYSLOG

```
elijah@degas:~$ cat /var/log/syslog.1 | grep cron
Jun 20 07:40:21 degas anacron[2795]: Job `cron.daily' terminated
Jun 20 07:40:21 degas anacron[2795]: Normal exit (1 job run)
Jun 20 08:17:01 degas CRON[3144]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 20 09:17:01 degas CRON[3228]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 20 10:17:01 degas CRON[4893]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 20 11:17:01 degas CRON[8737]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 20 12:17:01 degas CRON[10192]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 20 13:17:01 degas CRON[11870]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 20 14:17:01 degas CRON[12829]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 20 15:17:01 degas CRON[13614]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 20 15:54:28 degas crontab[14446]: (root) BEGIN EDIT (root)
Jun 20 15:55:27 degas crontab[14446]: (root) END EDIT (root)
Jun 20 15:55:29 degas crontab[14460]: (root) LIST (root)
Jun 20 16:17:01 degas CRON[14770]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 20 16:44:04 degas crontab[14911]: (root) DELETE (root)
Jun 20 16:44:07 degas crontab[14913]: (root) LIST (root)
Jun 20 17:17:01 degas CRON[15713]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 20 18:17:01 degas CRON[15842]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 20 19:17:01 degas CRON[15928]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 20 20:17:01 degas CRON[16023]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 20 21:17:01 degas CRON[16110]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 20 22:17:01 degas CRON[16212]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 20 23:17:01 degas CRON[16300]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 21 00:00:01 degas CRON[16372]: (root) CMD (invoke-rc.d atop _cron)
Jun 21 00:17:01 degas CRON[16437]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 21 01:17:01 degas CRON[16525]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 21 02:17:01 degas CRON[16612]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 21 03:17:01 degas CRON[16701]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 21 04:17:01 degas CRON[16798]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 21 05:17:01 degas CRON[16886]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 21 06:17:01 degas CRON[16974]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 21 06:25:01 degas CRON[16988]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily ))
Jun 21 07:17:01 degas CRON[17061]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 21 07:30:01 degas CRON[17083]: (root) CMD (start -q anacron || :)
Jun 21 07:30:01 degas anacron[17086]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2016-06-21
Jun 21 07:30:01 degas anacron[17086]: Will run job `cron.daily' in 5 min.
Jun 21 07:30:01 degas anacron[17086]: Jobs will be executed sequentially
Jun 21 07:35:01 degas anacron[17086]: Job `cron.daily' started
Jun 21 07:35:01 degas anacron[17099]: Updated timestamp for job `cron.daily' to 2016-06-21
```

## RSNAPSHOT TEST

```
elijah@degas:~$ /usr/bin/rsnapshot -t hourly
echo 23633 > /var/run/rsnapshot.pid 
/bin/rm -rf /media/backup/hourly.5/ 
mv /media/backup/hourly.4/ /media/backup/hourly.5/ 
mv /media/backup/hourly.3/ /media/backup/hourly.4/ 
mv /media/backup/hourly.2/ /media/backup/hourly.3/ 
mv /media/backup/hourly.1/ /media/backup/hourly.2/ 
/bin/cp -al /media/backup/hourly.0 /media/backup/hourly.1 
/usr/bin/rsync -a --delete --numeric-ids --relative --delete-excluded \
    --exclude=/var/ --exclude=/space/ --exclude=/nfs/ --exclude=/media/ \
    --exclude=/proc/ --exclude=/sys/ --exclude=/dev/ --exclude=/tmp/ \
    --exclude=/cdrom/ --exclude=media/backup /. \
    /media/backup/hourly.0/Backup 
touch /media/backup/hourly.0/
```

Comment: is `crond` still alive?

Comment: How can I check? I did `sudo ps aux | grep crond` and got `elijah    3795  0.0  0.0   9388   952 pts/10   S+   16:46   0:00 grep --color=auto crond` which I think is just the grep command I ran....

Comment: Your `ps|grep` command is correct, so perhaps cron got killed, eg because you ran out of memory. Look through the logs in /var/log/ depending on your system.

Comment: found some info in `/var/log/syslog.1`, you can see where I removed the crontab for root yesterday, as per roaima

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some [extended discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41467/discussion-between-elijah-and-roaima) it appears that the filesystem may corrupted. As an example, `rm -rf` fails - as root - on a normal tree of files.

After unmounting the filesystem, `fsck` identified it as NTFS.

Frustratingly I have seen NTFS fail on other Linux-based platforms under the heavy loads incurred from `rsnapshot`. There's nothing sufficiently repeatable with which a bug can be filed, but a week's worth of `rsnapshots` can usually corrupt the filesystem.

My recommendation is to replace the NTFS filesystem with something native to a Linux-based system, such as ext4. As an aside, if the backups must be accessed from a Windows platform, I have had good use from [the Ext2FSD utility and driver for extN filesystems](http://www.ext2fsd.com/) (also at [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fsd/)).

Answer (score 4):

This original advice applies only to **Debian-based distributions**:

The two `crontab` segments you've shown are not the same `crontab`. So your jobs are running twice (once from `/etc/cron.d/rsnapshot` and once from `crontab -l`).

Remove one set, for example with `sudo crontab -r`, and it'll start working properly.

---

The next suggestion is to **ensure that `sync_first` is not set** in the `/etc/rsnapshot.conf` file. (Or if it is, that it's `0`.) Otherwise although the cycling of rsnapshot directories will occur, no backup will actually get taken without an explicit `rsnapshot sync` command.

Comment: executed `sudo crontab -r` yesterday, but still haven't seen any action this morning. edited question to include syslog

Comment: OK. Interesting discovery (on my part) is that `/etc/cron.d` is a Debian extension and apparently not supported by other distributions. @Elijah, since you appear not to be using Debian please can you add back root's `crontab` and (for sake of form) comment out the entries in your `/etc/cron.d/rsnapshot`

Comment: @Elijah please can you confirm that in your `/etc/rsnapshot.conf` you do not have `sync_first 1` configured.

Comment: `sync_first` is commented out completely

Comment: also just to clarify, the machine in question is running ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Does `/var/log/rsnapshot.log` (I think) shed any light on the matter? If you run `/usr/bin/rsnapshot -t hourly` what does it show?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41467/discussion-between-elijah-and-roaima).